# Flex 4: detect unsupported glyphs (non-embedded fonts)

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, flex4

My app does the following:

1. enumerate fonts installed on the clients machine, and populate a dropdown list with them
2. present a s:TextArea with special characters (like äöü)
3. update the TextArea's font family to the one selected in the dropdown

After it updates, there seems to be three possible results: the correct glyph, a blank space, or a fallback glyph in a device font (seems to be _serif, though the CSS style is _typewriter).  **My goal is to programmatically detect whether a device font supports all the glyphs in a chosen user font.**

I have tried getBounds on various children (to detect 0 width, etc.), getting info about atoms, and comparing fontFamily for a correct glyph against fontFamily for a blank or fallback glyph.  For formatting changes that dispatch a UpdateCompleteEvent or CompositionCompleteEvent, i am always doing my checks after it completes.

Is there another way to approach this, or am I missing something?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[enumerateFonts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts%28%29)

[hasGlyphs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#hasGlyphs%28%29)

Comment: hasGlyphs looks promising, but how would i create an instance of the font from enumerateFonts(true)?  I'm not working with embedded fonts.

Comment: Check out the comments in the bottom of the docs, someone says it doesn't work for device fonts, with regard to how to load up the fonts, it looks like you can just use a Loader, more on it here: http://labs.tomasino.org/2009/07/16/flash-as3-runtime-font-manager/

Comment: These are still fonts that need to be explicitly embedded, right?  I'm reading a list of device fonts on the client's computer.

Comment: I think it's both embedded and device fonts based on this bit:  _enumerated = Font.enumerateFonts(true);

Comment: Ah looking back at that I may be wrong, it looks like you're right he's just loading those by giving them a URL to load from not off the device, sorry I misunderstood what was happening in that post.

Comment: Okay how about this bit: http://www.betriebsraum.de/blog/2007/06/22/runtime-font-loading-with-as3-flash-cs3-not-flex/

Comment: That one says "not Flex"!  Its not required for me I guess.  But these are still embedded; my font names are based on the user's device fonts.  This question is more about determining how the glyph is drawn after selecting an arbitrary font.

Comment: Hey Ethan so I just did a test, I was talking more about being able to load a Font object rather than anything else in that article (also the not flex part doesn't really matter since it's all AS3) I wrote up a little test to enumerate my device fonts and create a label using each displaying the font name and where it's resolved from, that all worked fine enumerateFonts returns Font typed objects however as the comment in the docs says hasGlyphs doesn't seem to work on device fonts, so sorry to say I don't have a solution. http://shaunhusain.com/TestDynamicFontLoading/

Comment: One more thing, is this a web application or a desktop application, if the latter you may be able to use Merapi to communicate with a java class and write up a small java class that deals with doing the check for you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29